# How to pull the delta data through Web api call

Tags: c#, api, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have been built an azure function app to pull the data through API call. The limit of the api call is 300 and the number of api exceeds when I pull history data each time. Is there any way where I can call the delta record each time when the function triggers.

Example:

I want to pull category *name* and *categoryid* (Incremental number) from a forum. Initially I load 500 categories, then it increased to 750. Is it possible to pull only the next 250 categories?

Is there any way to handle the api call exceed exception?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to redesign your API to support a **take**  and **skip** mechanism.

You might be able to do it by either using optional parameters in the existing operation (method) or by creating dedicated operations (methods) and routing to the appropriate operation using the **URL** structure.